# How do I make a Hamburger menu cover the whole viewport when open

Tags: html, css, navigation, display

I have a working hamburger menu using CSS only. My issue is that I'd like the menu to fill the whole screen when it's open. At the moment when it's open everything on my page gets shown below the menu like this:

[image]

And I'd like it to look like this:

[image]

I've tried adding `min-height: 100vh` to all the different classes in my CSS.

```css
.header {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 3;
  background-color: #202124;
}

.header ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.header li {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 22px;
}

.header ul a {
  display: block;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.header ul a:hover {
  color: #BDBDBD;
}

.header .logo {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

.header .menu {
  clear: both;
  max-height: 0;
  transition: max-height .2s ease-out;
}

.header .menu-icon {
  padding: 28px 20px;
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.header .menu-icon .nav-icon {
  background: #cccccc;
  display: block;
  height: 2px;
  width: 18px;
  position: relative;
  transition: background .2s ease-out;
}

.header .menu-icon .nav-icon:before {
  background: #cccccc;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all .2s ease-out;
  top: 5px;
}

.header .menu-icon .nav-icon:after {
  background: #cccccc;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all .2s ease-out;
  top: -5px;
}

.header .menu-btn {
  display: none;
}

.header .menu-btn:checked~.menu {
  max-height: 240px;
}

.header .menu-btn:checked~.menu-icon .nav-icon {
  background: transparent;
}

.header .menu-btn:checked~.menu-icon .nav-icon:before {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  top: 0;
}

.header .menu-btn:checked~.menu-icon .nav-icon::after {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  top: 0;
}

@media (min-width:48em) {
  .header li {
    float: left;
  }
  .header li a {
    padding: 20px 30px;
  }
  .header .menu {
    clear: none;
    float: right;
    max-height: none;
  }
  .header .menu-icon {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <a href="/" class="logo"><span class="logo-yellow">L</span><span class="logo-green">K</span></a>
  
  <input class="menu-btn" type="checkbox" id="menu-btn">
  <label class="menu-icon" for="menu-btn"><span class="nav-icon"></span></label>
  
  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Browse</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

.header {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 3;
  background-color: #202124;
}

.header ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.header li {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 22px;
}

.header ul a {
  display: block;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.header ul a:hover {
  color: #BDBDBD;
}

.header .logo {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

.header .menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #202124;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  overflow-y: auto;
  max-height: 0;
  transition: max-height .2s ease-out;
}

.header .menu li {
  display: block;
  padding: 20px 0;
}

.header .menu a {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 22px;
}

.header .menu a:hover {
  color: #BDBDBD;
}

.header .menu-icon {
  padding: 28px 20px;
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.header .menu-icon .nav-icon {
  background: #cccccc;
  display: block;
  height: 2px;
  width: 18px;
  position: relative;
  transition: background .2s ease-out;
}

.header .menu-icon .nav-icon:before {
  background: #cccccc;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all .2s ease-out;
  top: 5px;
}

.header .menu-icon .nav-icon:after {
  background: #cccccc;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all .2s ease-out;
  top: -5px;
}

.header .menu-btn {
  display: none;
}

.header .menu-btn:checked~.menu {
  max-height: 100%;
}

.header .menu-btn:checked~.menu-icon .nav-icon {
  background: transparent;
}

.header .menu-btn:checked~.menu-icon .nav-icon:before {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  top: 0;
}

.header .menu-btn:checked~.menu-icon .nav-icon::after {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  top: 0;
}

@media (min-width:48em) {
  .header li {
    float: left;
  }
  .header li a {
    padding: 20px 30px;
  }
  .header .menu {
    clear: none;
    float: right;
    max-height: none;
  }
  .header .menu-icon {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <a href="/" class="logo"><span class="logo-yellow">L</span><span class="logo-green">K</span></a>

  <input class="menu-btn" type="checkbox" id="menu-btn">
  <label class="menu-icon" for="menu-btn"><span class="nav-icon"></span></label>

  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Browse</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is add height: 100vh to your `.header .menu-btn:checked~.menu` class. You can also change width to 'vw' so it takes up the entire width on the browser. See below

```
.header .menu {
   clear: both;
   height: 0;
   transition: height .2s ease-out;
}
.header .menu-btn:checked~.menu {
   height: 100vh;
}
```